Ubuntu desktop (gnome) with wsl
Is it possible to install and use Ubuntu desktop (preferably Gnome) via wsl. I don't just want to start individual Ubuntu apps, but work completely via Ubuntu Desktop.

It's a common question that has been asked several times here on AU, so yes, see the other question for some possibilities, but as a heads-up, none of them are ideal.  When you are running WSL, Windows is your desktop environment.  It's very difficult to run two different desktop environments as each has its own ideas of the resources (and keybindings) it wants to handle.  If you really want to run Gnome inside Windows, a VM is a better option than WSL since the VM managers have ways to constrain the VM to its own virtual display.
